# Symfony3 Highcharts pie chart blank

Tags: symfony, highcharts, pie-chart

I started with Highcharts today in a symfony3 project and have the line charts working great. I'm having trouble rendering a pie chart and I'm beating my head on the wall trying to figure out why it's not working.

I can reproduce the basic pie chart (like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/)) if I render directly in javascript in my twig template, and it looks as expected. BUT if I try to render from my controller I get a blank image where the pie chart should be. My chart title is there so I know I'm rendering to the correct div. But the chart is blank. I've even tried very simple data structures (like an array of numbers as suggested by the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cpie%3E.data)) with no luck. This must be something simple. Help!

**My controller:**

```
public function piechartAction()
{
    $data = [["name"=> 'Microsoft Internet Explorer', "y"=> 56.33],
        ["name"=> 'Chrome', "data"=> 24.03],
        ["name"=> 'Firefox', "y"=> 10.38],
        ["name"=> 'Safari', "y"=> 4.77],
        ["name"=> 'Opera', "y"=> 0.91],
        ["name"=> 'Proprietary or Undetectable', "y"=> 0.2]];

    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('container');
    $ob->chart->type('pie');
    $ob->title->text('My Pie Chart');
    $ob->series(array("data"=>$data));

    return $this->render('dashboard/test.html.twig', [
        'mypiechart' => $ob
    ]);
}
```

And my **twig template**:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            {{ chart(mypiechart) }}
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what is the php library you use?

Comment: PHP version 5.6.3, Symfony v.3.2.6

Comment: I should also point out that I'm using  https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle

Comment: maybe you can try to remove the document ready like the example

Comment: No effect. But it's nice to drop some lines of code, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this. For anyone looking in the future, here's what I had wrong:
My setting of series data was not the correct format.

Here's my new (working) controller:

```
public function piechartAction()
{
    $data = [
        ['Microsoft Internet Explorer', 56.33],
        ['Chrome', 24.03],
        ['Firefox', 10.38],
        ['Safari', 4.77],
        ['Opera', 0.91],
        ['Proprietary or Undetectable', 0.2]
    ];

    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('container');
    $ob->chart->type('pie');
    $ob->title->text('My Pie Chart');
    $ob->series(array(array("data"=>$data)));

    return $this->render('dashboard/test.html.twig', [
        'mypiechart' => $ob
    ]);
}
```

I found this by studying the "cookbook" associated with this bundle ([here](https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/cookbook.md)); there is a listing for a drill-down pie chart.